NGINX x-forwarded-proto not working
I have an ASP.NET app hosted in a Docker container, with a NGINX reverse proxy, hosted on a VPS. When running in production, the x-forwarded-proto header isn't being passed.
From what I understand, this should return the x-forwarded-proto header
curl -I https://awaken.hanumaninstitute.com

The result is
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.22.1
Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2024 02:35:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

The NGINX server block is this
server {
server_name   awaken.hanumaninstitute.com;

location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
root /var/www/certbot;
}

location / {
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5009/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/awaken.hanumaninstitute.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/awaken.hanumaninstitute.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

The ASP.NET app has this
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

Server is Debian.
What am I missing? Why isn't x-forwarded-proto working?

How did you verify that the configuration is not working and this is not an issue on the origin host?

I had similar issue with hosting asp.net core app on debian server with nginx. I also thought that the issue is in nginx configuration but it was not...
Your nginx configuration looks good. The magic happens in this code:
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

This code reads the XForwardedFor and XForwardedProto headers and sets headers values to HttpContext properties like this:

X-Forwarded-For to HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
X-Forwarded-Proto to HttpContext.Request.Scheme

Documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-8.0
If you want to verify, that nginx really provides X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers place a simple middleware before app.UseForwardedHeaders().
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    //This will log all available headers in http request, your log MinimumLevel must be set to information
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var headers = context.Request.Headers.Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value });

        logger.LogInformation("Headers: {@Headers}", headers);

        await next();
    });

    // this will read X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers and remove them from context.Request.Headers
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
    
    // here you can see if the app.UseForwardedHeaders() works as expected
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var xForwardedForHeaderValue = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

        var XForwardedProtoHeaderValue = context.Request.Scheme;

        logger.LogInformation("IP: {Ip}, scheme: {Scheme}", xForwardedForHeaderValue, XForwardedProtoHeaderValue);

        await next();
    });

    // the rest of your code
}


I found out that ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor does NOT WORK by default without adding additional configuration for allowed hosts. Removing For and leaving only Proto fixed the problem.
